# MySQL and speed up

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL database with several tables. But one tabel contains af 1,400,000 rows. I need to get the 50,000 rows with the highest value in one field. A field that counts visitors.

```
SELECT uid, title, number, views 
FROM ct 
WHERE hidden = 0 
AND deleted = 0 
AND number > 0 
AND status LIKE 'active' 
order by views desc 
limit 0, 50000
```

It is extremely slow. The database is InnoDB and title, number and views are all indexed.

How can I speed up the selection?

From EXPLAIN:

```
1  SIMPLE  ct  ALL  number_index  NULL  NULL  NULL  1465440 Using where; Using filesort
```

After indexing Status
From EXPLAIN:

```
1  SIMPLE  ct  range  number_index,status  status  302  NULL  732720 Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Could you please share the query plan by running : EXPLAIN SELECT uid, title, number, views FROM ct WHERE hidden = 0 AND deleted = 0 AND number > 0 AND status LIKE 'active' order by views desc limit 0, 50000

Comment: Question updated

Comment: `status LIKE 'active'` uh, is the `status` field contains anything other than active and inactive? why are you using `like` in particular? `views` being indexed is kinda weird, is it used to **identify** stuff?

Comment: Status contains 5 or 6 different things. "pending", "ended" and other things. No, vies is only an integer field, I hust tried to index it to see if that would speed op the process.

Comment: After checking your query plan, It seems that your query didn't use any indexes you defined. To obtain result, It performed full table scan(ALL)

Comment: Okay, Status wasn't indexed maybe. I indexed it and did a EXPLAIN again and the number in the column Rows was much lower.

Comment: Table join changed from ALL(Full Table Scan) to Range which is a good sign. You need to make small changes and test again by running explain select ...... This is the way of improving your query.

Comment: I think @BillKarwin is a real expert, and you need to take his opinion.

Comment: When asking query optimization question, please include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` so we know your data types, indexes, and constraints. Otherwise we're guessing.

Comment: Please post the table schema

Comment: Hello @BillKarwin Let's assume for a second that OP doesn't want to share the table description, and only we have optimizer(query plan).  Also There is a big table consisting of 1.4 million rows which OP specified in the question.  Under these conditions, what is the best strategy to follow? we will focus only on indexes? what other options we should have(table partition etc... )? thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows do you have matching

```
WHERE hidden = 0 
AND deleted = 0 
AND number > 0 
AND status LIKE 'active'
```

?

If the answer is more than 70000 or so, then the short answer is that there is nothing you can do to speed things up. If it is significantly less then you will get some improvement with an index on hidden, deleted, number and status - how much of a speed up depends on the order of these attributes in the index and the cardinality for each of the attributes (nint: you want your highest cardinality entries first).

Comment: Yes, I have more than 700,000 rows, but need to show the 50,000 of them.

Answer (score 0):

This *composite* index *may* speed it up:

```
INDEX(hidden, deleted, status, number, views)
```

The real problem is shoveling 50K rows to the client.  What the heck will the client do with that many rows?

However, "the 50,000 rows with the highest value in one field" is not what your query finds.  Perhaps you first need to find "the highest value" in that field.  Then search for all rows with *that* value in that field??

Answer (score 0):

Showing 50k rows is always going to be costly. Just transferring the result set over the network is going to take a while. So there's a limit to how much you can "optimize" the query if the result set is that large. I'd seriously reconsider a design that required a result of 50k rows.

As for the best index for this query, the usual rule applies: use a compound index, consisting of the columns in equality conditions first, then ONE column used in range conditions. In your case, I would suggest:

```
alter table cte add index (hidden, deleted, status, number)
```

The first three may be in any order, since they're all equality conditions. Then `number` because it's a range condition. There's no way to optimize the ORDER BY, because the range condition spoils that.

A comment asked about partitioning or other methods of optimizing. I don't think it's likely that partitioning pruning will help.

The other method of optimizing I'd use is archiving. How many of the 1.4 million rows are hidden or deleted? Why not move those rows to another table, or to cold storage, or simply delete them. That would keep the active table smaller, and easier to keep in the buffer pool.